# How to generate a unique ID for every insert statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to give a unique ID for every insert statement I make, this is so I can see what rows was inserted together. I prefer that the unique "insert ID" start at 1 and increases by one like the `IDENTITY(1,1)` for rows.

Is there a easy way like `IDENTITY` to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[factTrade] 
(
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [insertedID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
      [price] [decimal](20, 10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[factTrade] ([insertedID], [quantity], [price])
VALUES (1, 6, 2.5), (1, 4, 3.7), (1, 3, 4.1), (1, 7, 8.5),

INSERT INTO [dbo].[factTrade] ([insertedID], [quantity], [price])
VALUES (2, 5, 5.2), (2, 1, 4.6)
```

Comment: uhm, what would be the difference between your `ID` column and `insertedId`?

Comment: Why not just have a DateCreated column? It would be a datetime column that is NOT NULL with default of GETDATE(). Otherwise you would have to go through a LOT of effort to accomplish something like this. You would need to use a sequence and likely create an instead of trigger so you can micro-manage each insert.

Comment: In SQL Server **2012** and newer, I'd use a `SEQUENCE` to hand out unique sequence numbers for each insert

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the solution you asked for, but you could add a column with a default timestamp to find all rows inserted at the same time.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.factTrade 
ADD InsertDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
```

Comment: Will the GETDATE() give me the same DATETIME if I insert 1.000.000 values in one insert statement?

Comment: @Aabling I just did a minor test and as long as it's the same batch, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Guids are handy for things like that.

```
declare @insertid uniqueidentifier = newid();
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[factTrade](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [insertedID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
  [price] [decimal](20, 10) NOT NULL,
  [insertid] [uniqueidentifier] not null
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[factTrade]
  ([insertedID]
  ,[quantity]
  ,[price]
  ,[insertid]
 )
VALUES
  (1, 6, 2.5,@insertid),
  (1, 4, 3.7,@insertid),
  (1, 3, 4.1,@insertid),
  (1, 7, 8.5,@insertid)
set @insertid = newid();  --get another guid
INSERT INTO [dbo].[factTrade]
  ([insertedID]
  ,[quantity]
  ,[price]
  ,[insertid]
)
VALUES
  (2, 5, 5.2,@insertid),
  (2, 1, 4.6,@insertid)
```

Comment: The only issue is that this solution requires you to add this code to every single statement that inserts into this table.

Comment: @ArthurD I do realize that, but I don't believe the OP said that was unacceptable.  If it isn't feasible, then the other answers here may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an integer value, then you can create another table:

```
CREATE TABLE inserts ([ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)...)
```

Then from your app, insert a row into this, then use the generated identity value (`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`).

```
INSERT inserts DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT @insertId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: If you use this approach you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, thank you for all the suggestions and comments.

```
DECLARE @insertedID INT

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[factTrade]
(
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [insertedID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
      [price] [decimal](20, 10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[factTradeInsertedID] AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1

SET @insertedID = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[factTradeInsertedID] --1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[factTrade] 
           ([insertedID]
           ,[quantity]
           ,[price])
    VALUES 
           (@insertedID, 6, 2.5)
           ,(@insertedID, 4, 3.7)
           ,(@insertedID, 3, 4.1)
           ,(@insertedID, 7, 8.5)


SET @insertedID = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[factTradeInsertedID] --2

INSERT INTO [dbo].[factTrade] 
           ([insertedID]
           ,[quantity]
           ,[price])
    VALUES 
           (@insertedID, 5, 5.2)
           ,(@insertedID, 1, 4.6)
```